# Bluemix plugin to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

i am trying to download bluemix plugin to my eclipse, but everytime I do this, i get this error. I saw some people with the same problem, but they don't know the answer as well.

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:

> (profile=C__Users_PauliusPC_eclipse_java-mars_eclipse,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Unable to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/cft/1.0.M3.1/org.eclipse.cft-1.0.0.v201603222052/plugins/org.eclipse.cft.server.core_1.0.101.v201603222052.jar.
>   Read timed out

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the following to the eclipse.ini file to see if it helps the issue?

```
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf.retry=15
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=10000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=10000
```